# Custom Chef handlers

Tags: chef-infra, handler

I am trying to understand the Chef documentation on [Custom Handlers](https://docs.chef.io/handlers/#custom-handlers).

The steps seem easy enough but I still don't understand how it works.

1. Download the chef_handler cookbook
2. Create a custom handler
3. Write a recipe using the chef_handler resource
4. Add that recipe to a node’s run-list, often as the first recipe in that run-list

Step 1 is no longer necessary as `chef_handler` cookbook is now part of Chef.

Step 2 creates a handler. The example given is

```rb
require 'net/smtp'

module OrgName
  class SendEmail < Chef::Handler
    def report
      if run_status.failed? then
        message  = "From: sender_name <sender@example.com>\n"
        message << "To: recipient_address <recipient@example.com>\n"
        message << "Subject: chef-client Run Failed\n"
        message << "Date: #{Time.now.rfc2822}\n\n"
        message << "Chef run failed on #{node.name}\n"
        message << "#{run_status.formatted_exception}\n"
        message << Array(backtrace).join('\n')
        Net::SMTP.start('your.smtp.server', 25) do |smtp|
          smtp.send_message message, 'sender@example', 'recipient@example'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now comes step 3 which I don't understand, add the following to a recipe

```rb
send_email 'blah' do
  # recipe code
end
```

When I run my recipe it just produces the error message which I expected to begin with:

```
FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `send_email` for cookbook: test, recipe: default :Chef::Recipe
```

How is this supposed to work? Are there other simple but working examples of custom handlers?

For Chef 15.0.300

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation on Chef handlers is a little unclear indeed at first look. Looking into more details, one thing is clear. [chef_handler](https://docs.chef.io/resources/chef_handler/) is a Chef resource (since Chef client 14). It supports two handlers by default - `JsonFile` and `ErrorReport`.

There is more documentation on [custom handlers](https://docs.chef.io/handlers/). This shows that we need to have some `chef_gem` installed for the custom handler(s) to work (apart from the above two).

> [Simple Email](https://rubygems.org/gems/chef-handler-mail)
>
> A handler that collects exception and report handler data and then uses pony to send email reports that are based on Erubis templates.

Connecting the dots... then we should have a recipe that installs the `chef_gem` and enables the handler. I created a separate cookbook, which can be reused by other cookbooks.

**In the below example, I have a cookbook `my_handlers`:**

```
recipes/json.rb
recipes/error_report.rb
recipes/email.rb
libraries/send_mail.rb
```

**In `my_handlers/recipes/email.rb`:**

```ruby
chef_gem 'chef-handler-mail'

chef_handler 'MailHandler' do
  source 'chef/handler/mail'
  arguments :to_address => 'root'
  action :enable
end
```

**In `my_handlers/libraries/send_mail.rb`:**

```ruby
require 'net/smtp'

module HandlerSendEmail
  class Helper

    def send_email_on_run_failure(node_name)
      message = "From: Chef <chef@chef.io>\n"
      message << "To: Grant <grantmc@chef.io>\n"
      message << "Subject: Chef run failed\n"
      message << "Date: #{Time.now.rfc2822}\n\n"
      message << "Chef run failed on #{node_name}\n"
      Net::SMTP.start('your.smtp.server', 25) do |smtp|
        smtp.send_message message, 'chef@chef.io', 'grantmc@chef.io'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

*Now I have something I can reuse in other cookbooks and choose the handler I want to enable.*

**Let's say I have a cookbook `cookbook1` in which I want to use the email handler on failure:**

**In `cookbook1/metadata.rb`:**

```ruby
depends 'my_handlers'
```

**In `recipes/default.rb`:**

```ruby
# Enable the Chef email handler by calling "my_handler"
include_recipe 'my_handlers::email'

Chef.event_handler do
  on :run_failed do
    HandlerSendEmail::Helper.new.send_email_on_run_failure(Chef.run_context.node.name)
  end
end

# Usual resource declarations

ruby_block 'fail the run' do
  block do
    fail 'deliberately fail the run'
  end
end
```

If failure occurs (deliberately as above), Chef email handler is invoked and triggers an email indicating failure.

Answer (score 0):

I think step 3 is wrong in documentation. It should be like this:

```rb
# recipe:
chef_handler 'OrgName::SendEmail' do # Full class name
  # relative path to your handler
  source ::File.expandpath('../../files/default/handlers/send_mail.rb', __FILE__)
  arguments() # Hash or Array to pass to handler constructor
end
```

It is common to store handlers in `files/default/handlers/` directory in cookbook, that's why the `source` attribute is like this.
`arguments` is not required in your case as your `initialize` method in handler does not expect any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's possible to ship a handler as a library in your cookbook (as seshadri_c shows), there are advantages to treating it as a separate installable artifact.

Most of them boil down to handling fail states.  Packaging your handler as a Ruby gem or even just a separate file resource gives you the chance to treat it like regular, testable Ruby code.  You can run some specs on it before having your Chef client's Ruby installation load the handler, which can potentially fail your entire Chef run.  Then your recovery state becomes, "remove the cookbook containing the handler from all my node run lists, push a hotfix cookbook version, add the handler back into the run lists."

This is because `libraries/*` within a cookbook gets loaded pretty early in a Chef run, before the recipe itself gets evaluated and before Chef takes any actions on any resources you've declared.

The disadvantage of this approach is that it's more work up-front.  If you've been working with Chef for a while but you don't think of yourself as a Ruby developer, suddenly having to think about Ruby packaging is a hassle.  Do you have the infrastructure built up for that?  If you're going to go "the full Gemnasium," do you have access to a Gem repository?  Do you have to make one yourself?

(This is also before tackling the special chicken-and-egg problem presented by start handlers, which load so early in the Chef run that you basically just have access to `client.rb` and the local Chef Ruby installation...)

If you're messing around with a few easily-accessible hosts and want to add a report handler, you're probably fine to ship the handler's Ruby code right there in the cookbook.  But if your handler cookbook is going out to a large number of systems that are difficult to access in the event that you need to recover them, consider "promoting" your library code out of your cookbook and into its own individually-testable, individually-releasable package before using it on all those systems.

Even just distributing it alongside the cookbook in `files/*` and installing it as a `cookbook_file` could help you avoid some of those pitfalls, although some implementations of this could result in an updated handler not running until the first run *after* you deploy handler changes.  There are cookbook examples of this pattern out there on GitHub and on Supermarket for you to use as a model.

If you do go "full Ruby gem," there are of course lots of examples of CI pipelines and repository templates for building secure, well-behaved Ruby gems, testing them and publishing them to the Gem repository of your choosing.  [Datadog's handler gem][https://github.com/DataDog/chef-handler-datadog] and [handler recipe][https://github.com/DataDog/chef-datadog/blob/main/recipes/dd-handler.rb] in their cookbook spring to mind as examples.